# Java FX diving integerproperty

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to bind the text field with the property but it is giving the 
error, please see below. Thanks

```
  private static final IntegerProperty DIVISOR = new SimpleIntegerProperty(32);

  rateTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(params.rateProperty().divide(DIVISOR), new NumberStringConverter()); //bindBidirectional(javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding, javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you bind bidirectionally to an equation?  “rate / DIVISOR” is not something you can assign a value to.   For the same reason the code `rate / 32 = newRate;` will not compile.

What you can do is use a [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) and use listeners instead of binding:

```
NumberStringConverter converter = new NumberStringConverter();
TextFormatter<Number> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter);
params.rateProperty().addListener(
    (o, old, rate) -> formatter.setValue(rate.doubleValue() / DIVISOR.get()));
formatter.valueProperty().addListener(
    (o, old, rate) -> params.setRate(rate.doubleValue() * DIVISOR.get()));

rateTextField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

If DIVISOR never changes, you can make it a primitive int instead of a property:

```
private static final int DIVISOR = 32;

// ...

NumberStringConverter converter = new NumberStringConverter();
TextFormatter<Number> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter);
params.rateProperty().addListener(
    (o, old, rate) -> formatter.setValue(rate.doubleValue() / DIVISOR));
formatter.valueProperty().addListener(
    (o, old, rate) -> params.setRate(rate.doubleValue() * DIVISOR));

rateTextField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

Comment: hmm .. did you try this? Afair, the formatter's value is set from the textField, so binding it will blow ..

Comment: @kleopatra You’re right.  Updated to use only listeners (which I did test).

Comment: Yes, it worked. but I am not sure the solution above has any privilege over this .     rateTextField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    
                            params.setRate(Integer.parseInt(rateTextField.getText()) * DIVISOR);
                    }
                }
        );

  
  
   rateTextField.textProperty().setValue(String.valueOf((params.getRate() / DIVISOR)));